# Preenchimento automático da linha no datagridwier

Tags: c#

Boa tarde.
Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho um datagridwier e nele tenho uma coluna onde digito um código de um produto. Agora preciso que quando o usuário digitar o código de um produto na célula da coluna de código a teclar o enter  ele preencher os campo produto e também o combobox lote com dados de um select que trago do banco de dados. Como posso fazer isso?

segue abaixo a tela do meu datagridwier
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DADOSADVConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comando = null;
        public frmSoliciatcaoAmostraPic()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void lbl_email_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (txt_codcli.Text != "")
        {

            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT 
                                 SA.A1_NREDUZ AS CLIENTE, 
                                 +'(' + SA.A1_DDD + ')' + ' ' + SA.A1_TEL AS TELEFONE, 
                                 SA.A1_CEP AS CEP,
                                 SA.A1_END AS ENDERECO,
                                 SA.A1_BAIRRO AS BAIRRO,
                                 SA.A1_MUN AS CIDADE,
                                 SA.A1_EST AS ESTADO,
                                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(SA.A1_DTNASC AS DATE), 103) AS DATA
                            FROM SA1010 AS SA
                            WHERE SA.A1_COD = '" + txt_codcli.Text + "'", conex);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            conex.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                txt_cliente.Text          = dr["CLIENTE"].ToString();
                txt_telefone.Text         = dr["TELEFONE"].ToString();
                txt_cep.Text              = dr["CEP"].ToString();
                txt_endereco.Text         = dr["ENDERECO"].ToString();
                txt_bairro.Text           = dr["BAIRRO"].ToString();
                txt_cidade.Text           = dr["CIDADE"].ToString();
                txt_uf.Text               = dr["ESTADO"].ToString();
                txt_dtcadastro.Text       = dr["DATA"].ToString();
            }
            conex.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Código do cliente invalido, por favor digitar um código de clinete válido");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, acho se vc colocar os parte do código ajudaria bastante, mas eu tenho um projeto semelhando, mas eu alimento o Grid com um Array que recebo de um Webservices, vou colocar o código abaixo.

```
         // o Registro contem dada dado concatenado e separado por ";"   
        for (int i = 0; i < registros; i++)
        {
            dataGridPermissoes.Rows.Add();

            var metadadoscort = ListRegistros[i + 1];
            var Listametadados = metadadoscort.Split(';');

            var permissao = "";
            if (Listametadados[10].Equals("M"))
            {
                permissao = "Modificar";
            }
            else if (Listametadados[10].Equals("R"))
            {
                permissao = "Remover";
            }
            else
            {
                permissao = "Leitura";
            }
             // Em vez de vc colocar "Listametadados[]" vc vai colocar o campos da tabela.
            dataGridPermissoes.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Listametadados[2];
            dataGridPermissoes.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Listametadados[4];
            dataGridPermissoes.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Listametadados[6];
            dataGridPermissoes.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = Listametadados[8];
            dataGridPermissoes.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = permissao;
        }
```

Comment: Desculpe acabei de colocar o código na pergunta. Então o quer preciso e quando eu digitar o código de um produto na grid ele ja preencher as colunas automaticamente.Estava pensando em usar o KeyDown no conteúdo da célula, é possível?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, vc quer que na coluna código do Datagrid o usuário digite um código e quando eu sair da célula execute uma consulta e traga os resultados?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quando sair da celula execurtar um select onde ou traga o nome do produto e o lote e preenche o datagrid

Comment: Renan resolvi o problema mudando o tipo de inserção na grid, criei os campos que preciso que sejam preenchido na grid depois criei um botão de insert que insiro os dados na grid.Mas muito obrigado pela atenção.